# don't disable the checked checkbox jquery

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I have a bunch of checkboxes with a common attribute of `class="all"`I want to disable all checkboxes except the checkbox that was check because currently I cannot unchecked it. This code disables all checkboxes in `class="all"`. How do I exclude the checkbox that is currently checked from this code so that I can uncheck it?

```
 $('.all').click(function() {
    $('.all').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.all').click(function() {
    $('.all').not(this).attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
 });
```

Comment: @justeric I'd appreciate you marking the answer as well for others that may look at the question!

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes it says or else I would have marked it 6 minutes ago :)

Comment: @lucuma apparently there is some sort of wait time between asking and accepting? never seen it before today

Comment: @justeric thanks.. I didn't know that.. There are too many people that don't bother marking answers so that will just make it worse..

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#disable_all').click(function() {
   $('.all:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

note: `#disable_all` could be a button or a link